# npm errors while running npm install and npm update

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am getting the following error when run the following commands: 
`npm install` and `npm update`

> npm ERR! path /home/myusername/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/9a/e4/c8b1b5f5ecdb3896ae63d10f31b93c6e3785501944906912db49c8ba02da
>   npm ERR! code Unknown system error -117
>   npm ERR! errno -117
>   npm ERR! syscall open
>   npm ERR! Unknown system error -117: Unknown system error -117, open '/home/myusername/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/9a/e4/c8b1b5f5ecdb3896ae63d10f31b93c6e3785501944906912db49c8ba02da'
>   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     /home/myusername/.npm/_logs/2019-04-03T00_04_40_694Z-debug.log

I am not sure why this is happening.. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the stack trace located at:  /home/myusername/.npm/_logs/2019-04-03T00_04_40_694Z-debug.log ?

Answer (score 1):

Try opening cli with admin rights. It happens when there is permission error. If still persist then close all files opened in any editor.